# Is Assassination Classroom the Movie 365 Days a continuation of the manga?

Tags: assassination-classroom

Like I said in the title, is the movie a continuation of the manga from where it ended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's a recap movie with a little bit of extra content. ([Official site](http://www.ansatsu-anime.com/365days/) in Japanese; [ANN article](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-10-03/assassination-classroom-anime-film-2nd-teaser-video-streamed/.107187) in English.)

Comment: Really that's sad.